# DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for www.exampl.com - check that a DNS record exists for this domain

Tags: nginx, ssl, dns, certbot

I'm going to install SSL for nginx via certbot

But I face this error:  "DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) - check that a DNS record exists for this domain"

However, I have two A records in Cloudflare:

```
example.com     ip
www             ip
```

What should I do?

Comment: Disable the proxy in Cloudflare. If you go to the DNS section, there will be an orange cloud symbol. Click it to disable it and then retry the process.

Comment: its disabled before

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming, but besides that in similar cases if you give the real name involved you could get far better replies.. Other than that your current webhosting/DNS provider company should be able to help you.

Comment: This issue appears to occur when a CNAME record is not created. After you've created a CNAME record, try to generate SSL.

Answer (score 6):

When the *Let's Encrypt* Certbot tried to validate your domain, it failed to find the IP address (A record) of the domain to match if the certbot is running from the IP location.

**Possible Solution 1**

Check if the **Cloudflare proxy** is on for the A record. If it is in on state, turn it off. Usually, this is done by clicking the orange cloud icon on the DNS page for the A record.

**Possible Solution 2**

If it's already done and still you are facing errors, edit the **TTL (Time To Live)** field for the A record to `60`. Your domain DNS is not propagated and this might speed up the process.

**Possible Solution 3**

If none of the above works, there is something wrong with the certbot or the connection from the certbot to the DNS of your domain. Add `--debug-challenges` while you run the command to issue SSL. This might give you more info.

**Possible Solution 4**

One last resort is to try the manual mode. You can verify the domain ownership via `http` challenge instead of `dns` mode. Follow the instructions [here](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#manual) in the Certbot documentation.

However, you might need to associate the certificate once issued to your nginx configuration. Find the below config for your reference. You can easily use this make your service / website up and running after getting the certificate.

```
server {
        server_name example.com;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Comment: " Your domain DNS is not propagated " It never is, as DNS propagation does not exist.

Comment: By this, I meant the DNS changes are not propagated. Thanks for pointing out :)

Comment: There is no DNS propagation as the DNS is not top down, but bottom up, and only when caches expire. DNS changes do not propagate.

Comment: What if the DNS records are cached by the ISPs and take time to reflect the latest changes?

Comment: Yes, that is normal DNS behavior driven by records TTL. When it expires it is the ISP resolver that goes fetch the new record (bottom->up), it is not the authoritative nameserver pushing the new data.

Comment: Hmm, that's what I meant here by DNS propagation (DNS record changes). The certbot installed in the local machine will try to get the A record for a domain.

The DNS cache on the ISP side will resolve the old A record. Even if the TTL is set as low as 60, some ISPs have their self-paced process to update the cache.

Comment: Yes and it is still NOT propagation from upstream where the change appeared to downstream. It is just cache refresh upon expiration. Pull vs push.